# twisted gaussian integers; complex plane with a different basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, number-theory, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand a kind of twisted form of Gaussian integers. They are defined via
$$ w = e^{i \frac{2}{3} \pi}\\
R = \{ m + nw \mid m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$$

I tried to picture them by using the complex plane. Now the basis vectors are not $1$ and $i$ but $1$ and $e^{i \frac{2}{3} \pi}$ which -assuming a counterclockwise rotation- corresponds to the imaginary axis rotated $30^\circ$ to the left.

In order to find the correct grid, I drew equidistant circles for $m=1,2,3,...$. I marked the intersections of the circle with the axis and thus got the points $(0,1), (0,2), ...$ and $(1,0), (2,0), ...$.

How do I proceed now? Will I get the correct grid if I draw lines thorugh these points which are perpendicular to the corresponding axis and use their intersections as points? Or is something flawed with my way of picturing this?

Comment: these are called eisenstein integers

Comment: Thanks! By reading the wikipedia article I think I now get how to picture them.

Answer (score 1):

The following article [Hexagonal Global Parameterization of
Arbitrary Surfaces](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEMQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opus4.kobv.de%2Fopus4-matheon%2Ffiles%2F830%2FHexParam.pdf&ei=jh60VMu0Gsq9aaDQgGg&usg=AFQjCNF_l2R33KCvfiualS-nMYHscvCNZQ&bvm=bv.83339334,d.d2s) shows more (beautiful) pictures and gives an application of Eisenstein integers. The authors write: "We point out that in the hexagonal parameterization
this grid is the set of Eisenstein integers, which is different
from the Gauss integers used in the quadrangular case."